# Incompatible code with node version on repl.it

Tags: discord.js, replit

As you can see, this is regarding discord.js bot. I've already upgrade node.js on repl.it into version 16 but even after I update it, when I click run, the following error still pops up on the console.

> /home/runner/MathBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:32 const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (??)** operator is available only to node versions [14 and above](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) which is on **LTS** as of now, although [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) version 13 and above require node [version 16](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) which is labelled as *Current* by npm and contains the latest features, the error simply indicates that your node version is below 14.

You may try the following methods:

**Method 1:**

• Create a bash repl which defaults to node version 14 and further install a dependency [AbortController-Polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abortcontroller-polyfill) to fulfil the requirements of the features discord.js v13 needs to function

Define the AbortController globally like this: ​

```js
const { AbortController } = require('abortcontroller-polyfill/dist/cjs-ponyfill');
global.AbortController = AbortController;
```

**Method 2**

Step 1:

Add this to your `package.json`, ( this isn't malicious, it updates version to node 16 and forces to clean npm cache on replit so replit may not reject the process )

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node .",
  "node-update": "npm i --save-dev node@16 && npm config set prefix=$(pwd)/node_modules/node && export PATH=$(pwd)/node_modules/node/bin:$PATH",
  "node-clean": "rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json && npm cache clear --force && npm cache clean --force && npm i",
  "ez-v16": "npm run node-update && npm run node-clean-cache"
}
```

Step 2: 

Run this in your shell 
`npm run ez-v16`
 and press the run button.

Answer (score 1):

discord.js v13 only supports node versions of 16.6 and up. Head over to https://nodejs.org and grab the latest release.